# Visual graph editor with export to JSON file (or other structured file)

Tags: graphs, editor, metadata-editor

Looking for a visual interface I can edit a graph in and then export it to some structured file format (e.g. JSON). Searching "Graph editor" in Google only gets me graph editors that export image files.

By graph, I mean a set of nodes connected to each other via edges.

Other features that would be ideal:

- Can display nodes with long labels
- Can import an existing graph
- Ideally interface is online or compatible with Ubuntu or Mac OS X

Looking for a free or cheap solution. Max budget $20.

Comment: Welcome Noah! Can you update your question to indicate if you are looking for recommendations for gratis or commercial software (or either). If the latter, a price range will be helpful to finding you good answers. Thanks, and again, welcome! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've updated my question.